# Add product custom fields to cart and display them everywhere in WooCommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, product, advanced-custom-fields, custom-fields

Ive set up an ACF with 2 checkboxes, which are shown up in the product admin:
[image: product admin]

on the product frontend only the selected values form the backend are chooseable:
[image: product frontend]

Ive the following code im my funtions:

```
// Display on product page
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'display_acf_single_product_pages', 1 );
function display_acf_single_product_pages() {
    global $product;

    $colors  = get_field( 'colors',  $product->get_id() );
    $sizes = get_field( 'sizes', $product->get_id() );

    
    
    if( $colors ): ?>
<div class="vorcartbutton">
    <div class="vorcartbuttonlable">
<label for="cars">Farbe wählen:</label>
<select name="farbe" id="farbe">
    <?php foreach( $colors as $color ): ?>
        <option><span class="color"><?php echo $color['label']; ?></span></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
<br>
<?php

if( $sizes ): ?>
    <div class="vorcartbuttonlable">
<label for="cars">Größe wählen:</label>
<select name="groesse" id="groesse">
    <?php foreach( $sizes as $sizes ): ?>
        <option><span class="groesse"><?php echo $sizes['label']; ?></span></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<br>
<?php

   
}

// Display on cart and checkout
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'display_acf_on_cart_and_checkout', 10, 2 );
function display_acf_on_cart_and_checkout( $cart_data, $cart_item ) {
    $colors  = get_field( 'colors', $cart_item['product_id'] );
    $sizes = get_field( 'sizes', $cart_item['product_id'] );
    
    
 if ( ! empty($colors) ) {
        $custom_items[] = array( "name" => __("Farbe", "woocommerce"),  "value" => $colors  );
    }

    if ( ! empty($sizes) ) {
        $custom_items[] = array( "name" => __("Größe", "woocommerce"), "value" => $sizes );
    }
   
    return $custom_items;
}

// Display on orders and email notifications (save as custom order item meta data)
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'display_acf_on_orders_and_emails', 10, 4 );
function display_acf_on_orders_and_emails( $item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order ) {
    $colors  = get_field( 'colors', $values['product_id'] );
    $sizes = get_field( 'sizes', $values['product_id'] );

    if ( ! empty($colors) ) {
        $item->add_meta_data( __("size", "woocommerce"), $colors );
    }

    if ( ! empty($sizes) ) {
        $item->add_meta_data( __("color", "woocommerce"), $sizes );
    }
}
```

In the cart the values just show array:
[image: product3 array]

Can someone push me in the right direction, to get the correct values in the cart, checkout, mails and orders?

Originally taken from here [Display ACF product custom fields everywhere in WooCommerce 3+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65415903/display-acf-product-custom-fields-everywhere-in-woocommerce-3)

Comment: FYI: `for="cars"` in no way relates to `id="farbe"` or `id="groesse"`.  This is an example of bad copy-pasta.  Loic has addressed this mistake in his answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are mistakes and some missing things in your code. Instead use the following revisited code:

```
// Display on product page
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'display_acf_single_product_pages', 1 );
function display_acf_single_product_pages() {
    global $product;

    $colors = get_field( 'colors',  $product->get_id() );
    if ( ! empty($colors) ) {
        echo '<div class="vorcartbutton">
        <div class="vorcartbuttonlable">
        <label for="farbe">'. __("Farbe wählen") .':</label>
        <select name="farbe" id="farbe">';

        foreach ( $colors as $color ) {
            echo '<option value="'. $color['label'] .'"><span class="color">'. $color['label'] .'</span></option>';
        }
        echo '</select>
        </div><br>';
    }

    $sizes = get_field( 'sizes', $product->get_id() );
    if ( ! empty($sizes) ) {
        echo '<div class="vorcartbutton">
        <div class="vorcartbuttonlable">
        <label for="groesse">'. __("Größe wählen") .':</label>
        <select name="groesse" id="groesse">';

        foreach ( $sizes as $size ) {
            echo '<option value="'. $size['label'] .'"><span class="color">'. $size['label'] .'</span></option>';
        }
        echo '</select>
        </div><br>
        </div>';
    }
}

// Add as custom cart item data
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'save_acf_as_cart_item_data', 10, 2 );
function save_acf_as_cart_item_data( $cart_item_data, $cart_item ) {
    if ( isset($_POST['farbe']) || isset($_POST['groesse']) ) {
        if ( isset($_POST['farbe']) ) {
            $cart_item_data['farbe'] = esc_attr($_POST['farbe']);
        }
        if ( isset($_POST['groesse']) ) {
            $cart_item_data['groesse'] = esc_attr($_POST['groesse']);
        }
        $cart_item_data['unique_key'] = md5( microtime().rand() );
    }
    return $cart_item_data;
}

// Display on cart and checkout
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'display_acf_on_cart_and_checkout', 10, 2 );
function display_acf_on_cart_and_checkout( $cart_data, $cart_item ) {
    if ( isset($cart_item['farbe']) ) {
        $custom_items[] = array( 'name' => __("Farbe", "woocommerce"), 'value' => $cart_item['farbe'] );
    }

    if ( isset($cart_item['groesse']) ) {
        $custom_items[] = array( 'name' => __("Größe", "woocommerce"), 'value' => $cart_item['groesse'] );
    }
    return $custom_items;
}

// Display on orders and email notifications (save as custom order item meta data)
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'display_acf_on_orders_and_emails', 10, 4 );
function display_acf_on_orders_and_emails( $item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order ) {
    $colors  = get_field( 'colors', $values['product_id'] );
    $sizes = get_field( 'sizes', $values['product_id'] );

    if ( isset($values['farbe']) ) {
        $item->add_meta_data( 'farbe', $values['farbe'] );
    }

    if ( isset($values['groesse']) ) {
        $item->add_meta_data( 'groesse', $values['groesse'] );
    }
}

// Change displayed label for specific custom order item meta keys
add_filter('woocommerce_order_item_display_meta_key', 'filter_wc_order_item_display_meta_key', 10, 3 );
function filter_wc_order_item_display_meta_key( $display_key, $meta, $item ) {

    // Change displayed label for specific order item meta key
    if( is_admin() && $item->get_type() === 'line_item' ) {
        if( $meta->key === 'farbe' ) {
            $display_key = __("Farbe", "woocommerce");
        }
        if( $meta->key === 'groesse' ) {
            $display_key = __("Größe", "woocommerce");
        }
    }
    return $display_key;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: As for this answer, why not add the `class="color"` to the `<option>` tag and remove its `value` attribute since it would only duplicate the option's text?  ...then again, if every `<option>` is unconditionally receiving the class declaration, then that would argue that there is no value in nominating the class in the first place -- just target all `<option>` tags which are children of these identified `<select>`s for any css/js.  Right?