# Woocommerce save ACF Fields in orders meta data and display them in Cart, Orders and emails

Tags: woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, cart, orders

I'm new using Woocommerce, Snippets and ACF Fields, and I created meta fields into products, I want to get ACF Fields in cart items, and save them in orders table but is not working, I already check huge pages but still I don't find an answer to my need, can you help me, please? Thanks in advance.

I tried this code from the post [Add product custom fields to cart and display them everywhere in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67337904/add-product-custom-fields-to-cart-and-display-them-everywhere-in-woocommerce)

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_get_cart_item_from_session',  'cart_item_from_session' , 99, 2 );

function cart_item_from_session( $item_id, $data ) {
    $calories = $item_id->get_meta('acf-calories');
    $delivery_date = $item_id->get_meta('acf-delivery_date');
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_order_item_meta', 'add_item_meta_order', 10, 3 );

function add_item_meta_order( $item_id, $data ) {
        wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, 'acf-calories', "$calories", 'acf-delivery_date', "$delivery_date");
    }

// Display on product page
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'display_acf_single_product_pages', 1 );
function display_acf_single_product_pages() {
    global $product;

    $calories = get_field( 'acf-calories',  $product->get_id() );
   
    $delivery_date = get_field( 'acf-delivery_date', $product->get_id() );
   
}

// Add as custom cart item data
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'save_acf_as_cart_item_data', 10, 2 );
function save_acf_as_cart_item_data( $cart_item_data, $cart_item ) {
    $calories = $item_id->get_meta('acf-calories');
    $delivery_date = $item_id->get_meta('acf-delivery_date');
       
        $cart_item_data['unique_key'] = md5( microtime().rand() );
}    
    return $cart_item_data;


// Display on cart and checkout
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'display_acf_on_cart_and_checkout', 10, 2 );
function display_acf_on_cart_and_checkout( $cart_data, $cart_item ) {
    $calories = $item_id->get_meta('acf-calories');
    $delivery_date = $item_id->get_meta('acf-delivery_date');
    
    //I don't know if here I have to add some return?
}

// Display on orders and email notifications (save as custom order item meta data)
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'display_acf_on_orders_and_emails', 10, 4 );
function display_acf_on_orders_and_emails( $item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order ) {
    $calories = get_field( 'acf-calories', $values['product_id'] );
    $delivery_date = get_field( 'acf-delivery_date', $values['product_id'] );
    }


// Change displayed label for specific custom order item meta keys
add_filter('woocommerce_order_item_display_meta_key', 'filter_wc_order_item_display_meta_key', 10, 3 );
function filter_wc_order_item_display_meta_key( $display_key, $meta, $item ) {

    // Change displayed label for specific order item meta key
    if( is_admin() && $item->get_type() === 'line_item' ) {
        if( $meta->key === 'acf-calories' ) {
            $display_key = __("Calories", "woocommerce");
        }
        if( $meta->key === 'acf-delivery_date' ) {
            $display_key = __("Delivery Date", "woocommerce");
        }
    }
    return $display_key;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add custom product dimensions fields for Dokan vendors and administrators in WordPress, WooCommerce, and Dokan, you'll need to use hooks and filters. Here's the code and instructions on where to add it:

Add Custom Fields to the Product Edit Page:
You need to add custom fields for product dimensions on the product edit page for both vendors and administrators.

```
// Add custom product dimensions fields
function add_product_dimensions_fields() {
?>
<div class="product_dimensions">
    <p class="form-field dimensions_length_field">
        <label for="dimensions_length"><?php _e('Length', 'your-text-domain');>
    </label>
        <input type="text" id="dimensions_length" name="_dimensions_length" class="short" value="<?php echo esc_attr(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_dimensions_length', true)); ?>">
    </p>
    <p class="form-field dimensions_width_field">
        <label for="dimensions_width"><?php _e('Width', 'your-text-domain'); ?></label>
        <input type="text" id="dimensions_width" name="_dimensions_width" class="short" value="<?php echo esc_attr(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_dimensions_width', true)); ?>">
    </p>
    <p class="form-field dimensions_height_field">
        <label for="dimensions_height"><?php _e('Height', 'your-text-domain'); ?></label>
        <input type="text" id="dimensions_height" name="_dimensions_height" class="short" value="<?php echo esc_attr(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_dimensions_height', true)); ?>">
    </p>
</div>
<?php
}

 add_action('woocommerce_product_options_dimensions', 'add_product_dimensions_fields');
 add_action('dokan_product_edit_after_product_tags', 'add_product_dimensions_fields');
```

Save Custom Fields on Product Update:
You need to save the custom fields when a product is updated or added.

```
// Save custom product dimensions fields
function save_product_dimensions_fields($post_id) {
$dimensions_length = isset($_POST['_dimensions_length']) ? wc_clean($_POST['_dimensions_length']) : '';
$dimensions_width = isset($_POST['_dimensions_width']) ? wc_clean($_POST['_dimensions_width']) : '';
$dimensions_height = isset($_POST['_dimensions_height']) ? wc_clean($_POST['_dimensions_height']) : '';

update_post_meta($post_id, '_dimensions_length', $dimensions_length);
update_post_meta($post_id, '_dimensions_width', $dimensions_width);
update_post_meta($post_id, '_dimensions_height', $dimensions_height);
}

add_action('woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'save_product_dimensions_fields');
add_action('dokan_new_product_added', 'save_product_dimensions_fields');
add_action('dokan_product_updated', 'save_product_dimensions_fields');
```

Display Fields to Vendors and Admins on the Frontend:
To display the custom fields on the vendor and admin frontend, you can use similar code.

For the Dokan vendor frontend:

```
// Display custom product dimensions fields to vendors on frontend
function display_product_dimensions_on_vendor_frontend($post) {
?>
<div class="product_dimensions">
    <p><strong><?php _e('Product Dimensions:', 'your-text-domain'); ?></strong></p>
    <p><?php _e('Length:', 'your-text-domain'); ?> <?php echo esc_html(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_dimensions_length', true)); ?></p>
    <p><?php _e('Width:', 'your-text-domain'); ?> <?php echo esc_html(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_dimensions_width', true)); ?></p>
    <p><?php _e('Height:', 'your-text-domain'); ?> <?php echo esc_html(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_dimensions_height', true)); ?></p>
</div>
<?php
}
add_action('dokan_product_edit_after_main', 'display_product_dimensions_on_vendor_frontend');
```

For the admin frontend, you can create a custom dashboard widget or modify the product list table to display the dimensions.

Display Product Dimensions in Product List:
For displaying product dimensions in the product list table in the admin backend:

```
// Add custom columns to product list table
function add_product_dimensions_columns($columns) {
$columns['_dimensions_length'] = __('Length', 'your-text-domain');
$columns['_dimensions_width'] = __('Width', 'your-text-domain');
$columns['_dimensions_height'] = __('Height', 'your-text-domain');
return $columns;}

add_filter('manage_product_posts_columns', 'add_product_dimensions_columns');

// Display custom column data in product list table
function display_product_dimensions_columns($column, $post_id) {
if ($column === '_dimensions_length' || $column === '_dimensions_width' || $column === '_dimensions_height') {
    echo esc_html(get_post_meta($post_id, $column, true));
 }
}
add_action('manage_product_posts_custom_column', 'display_product_dimensions_columns', 10, 2);
```

Where to Add the Code:
You should add the code to your theme's functions.php file or in a custom plugin. Make sure to replace 'your-text-domain' with your actual text domain.

Remember to test this code on a development site first, and ensure you have a backup of your data before making changes to your live website.
where to fine this for admin product>product data>shipping  just under the shipping dimensions